# Can I create a custom Style() class in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, styles, ttk

```py
hstyle = ttk.Style()
hstyle.configure('head.TLabel',
                 bg = '#aad5df',
                 font = ("Arial Bold", 50),
                 justify = 'CENTER',
                 width = 20)
```

I am new to Python. I have written a small program and it works procedurally.

I am now converting it to classes. I am wondering if I can create a custom class for Styles.

I have an App window and 5 frames for the functionality. I want a header label for each frame.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the 5 frames using the custom style? If yes, you need a custom `Frame` instead.

Comment: No. The frame will just have a background color. I want a header label on each frame that contains the page name. If this is possible, I will create other class styles for the other labels and buttons I am using in my app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.